# Connect netbeans with vagrant

Tags: php, netbeans, vagrant

I have a project cloned from github repository on my vagrant machine. How can I open it with netbeans on my host machine, and make changes so that it automatically deploys to vagrant?

I have been thinking about SFTP, but I don't have vagrant password, user, or other things - it just starts with `vagrant ssh`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared folder for your sources to make it visible on your guest and host systems at the same time. Or if you want to sync between these two you can find the default key used by vagrant for SSH communication. Or customize it according to your needs (see http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html)